# How to get bytes from input type file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
 $(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function (e) {
    $.each($(e.target)[0].files, function (i, file) {
      // how to get byt
    });
});
```

how to get the bytes of the file too?

Comment: Do you mean the size of the file?

Comment: not, byte array or base64